# How to find cross-over point of running times of 2 algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to compare two sorting algorithms. Suppose that for all inputs of size `n`, the first algorithm runs in `8n^2` seconds, while the second algorithm runs in 64n lg n seconds. For which value of `n` does the first algorithm beat the second algorithm?

The answer is: `8n^2 < 64n lg n.`

```
2 <= n <= 43.
```

How do I derive it from the question? why isn't it.

```
8n^2 > 64n lg n
or  8n^2 = 64n lg n
```

And getting the values `2 <= n <= 43`. Sorry I'm new to this. Anyone can explain to me?

Comment: An interesting question for you: [Why is selection sort faster than bubble sort?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13106/why-is-selection-sort-faster-than-bubble-sort)

Comment: This has nothing to do with big Oh and friends. It's just algebra. f(n) = 8n^2; g(n) = 64n lg n; f(n) = g(n); solve for n.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, and not related to programming.

Comment: The title is no way related to question.Editing it!

Comment: To find cross-over point, simply solve the equation :
8n^2=64nlogn
Hint: You use binary search.

Answer (score 2):

You want `n` such that

```
   8n^2 < 64n lg n
=> 8n^2 - 64n lg n < 0
```

We [solve `h(n) = 8n^2 - 64n lg n` for its roots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%288n+%3D+64+log%28n%29%2Flog%282%29%29) and discover that it has roots at `n_1 ~= 1.100` and `n_2 ~= 43.559`. If we [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%288n%5E2+-+64+n+log%28n%29+%2F+log%282%29+from+n%3D0+to+50%29) this function, we see that it is positive when `n < n_1` and when `n > n_2`.

[image: Plot of 8^n2 - 64n lg n]

Thus, the quadratic algorithm exceeds the runtime for the [linearithmic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearithmic_time#Linearithmic.2Fquasilinear_time) algorithm when `n < n_1` or `n > n_2`. Therefore, the quadratic algorithm beats the linearithmic if `n` in `[1.1, 43.559]` which implies `2 <= n <= 43` since `n` must be integral. Otherwise, for all other `n`, the quadratic algorithm is inferior to the linearithmic algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me correctly, and trust me it's been a while, but all you'd really have to do is graph these curves to find the answer.  To understand the question better, graph a basic log function.  You will see that it accelerates quickly in the beginning and levels off as x becomes greater while the acceleration of the x^2 algorithm will continue to increase.  Look at the graph if you have a graphing calculator and it will help you to understand it better